# Debugging Limitation Of Object Properties In Windows CMD

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, debugging, cmd

I am **debugging** **Node.js** script on **windows** **command prompt** with '`node inspect app.js`'. The problem is when I use **repl** or **exec('someObject')** everytime I see only `5` properties even if the object has `more than 5` properties. Is it some configuration which I should change or ?

This is what I see every time on this or other `object` which I want to `inspect` in `cmd`. 
For example:

```
files.fileImg
{ domain: null,
  _events: Object,
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: 'undefined',
  size: 34814,
  ... } -> ***here there is more properties which are not shown***
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably more of a workaround than an answer, but you could always do either (depending on your object's structure, circular references etc):

```
debug> exec('console.log(x)')
< { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5, f: 6 }
```

or

```
debug> exec('JSON.stringify(x)')
< { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5, f: 6 }
```

or

```
debug> exec('require("util").inspect(x, {depth: null})')
'{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5, f: 6 }'
```

or any of the other one-line ways of dumping an object's contents.

Comment: Very interesting is this happening only on windows ?

Comment: I don't have access to a non-windows environment at the moment so I'm not able to confirm if your problem occurs only in Windows. However, these workarounds should work regardless of operating system and print full object (assuming you don't have circular refs etc).

Comment: Yes. I understand.